# Is it possible to assign the "Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings" permission set for B2B Commerce (CloudCraze) in a scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

Is it possible to assign the "Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings" permission set for B2B Commerce (CloudCraze) in a scratch org? If so, how? If not, why?

The managed package is installed and working with licenses in a dev hub org and I am able to install it in a scratch org via sfdx, using the Salesforce recommended way (https://sforce.co/36XsUbr).

However, I am not able to assign the "Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings" permission set. I get an error:

> "Can't assign permission set Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings to user User User. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Custom Permission B2BCommerceAdmin is not valid for this Permission Set."

There is a Custom Permission "B2BCommerceAdmin" that is part of the B2B managed package. I've tried isolating it by creating my own permission set and adding just it and then assigning that and I got the same error, so I believe it has something to do with this Custom Permission.

I am able to assign other B2B packaged permissions sets, such as "B2B Commerce Admin" without any problem.

Comment: I stopped looking as I am using B2B Commerce LEX which doesn't require any of this and works quite well with SFDX and scratch orgs.